# Criar link com dados de um form

Tags: javascript, formulário, algoritmo-de-busca, link

Tenho um site externo de pesquisa pronto onde os resultados da busca geram um link semelhante a este: `http://example.com/pesquisa?utf8=✓&search=itempesquisado&x=0&y=0`.

Gostaria de criar um form no meu site que levasse para este link externo, ou seja, quando o usuário digitar `itempesquisado` no campo e clicar em enviar deve ser direcionado para a página: `http://example.com/pesquisa?utf8=✓&search=itempesquisado&x=0&y=0`.

Comment: Procure colocar mais detalhes na sua dúvida, como por exemplo o código html do seu formulário.

Comment: O problema é que se o código fonte estiver num encoding  diferente do servidor, e/ou o usuário usar browser com outro encoding ao preencher o form, não vai servir pra muita coisa saber como veio o ✓. Melhor examinar os headers e explicitar nos parâmetros se estiver usando este dado para detecção do encoding, e usar entities ( utf8="&ccedil;" no código-fonte, por exemplo. )

Answer (score 2):

Tente este código HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form method="get" action="http://endereco.com.br/pesquisa" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
        <input type="hidden" name="utf8" value="✓">
        <input type="text" name="search" value="itempesquisado">
        <input type="hidden" name="x" value="0">
        <input type="hidden" name="y" value="0">
        <input type="submit" value="Pesquisar">
    </form>
<body>
</html>
```

- Você poderá ter dificuldade para transmitir/receber este símbolo ✓ (%E2%9C%93), se você puder mudar ele, vai facilitar.

Comment: "Você poderá ter dificuldade para transmitir este símbolo ✓ "Mas de repente a idéia é justamente testar no servidor como o símbolo foi :)

Comment: Bacco, olhando a chamada acho que a intenção foi essa mesmo. Criatividade mil :D.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly eu tentei deduzir a lógica, me pareceu o único motivo plausível :) em todo o caso, veja meu comment na pergunta sobre o risco de não funcionar como esperado.